# VSCode not auto closing parenthesis in JavaScript files

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using VSCode for coding my projects but while it adds parenthesis and curly braces in other types of files it doesn't auto adds in js files or JSX files

see here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Okl3d.gif

I have researched for it and I found that I need to change the `Editor: Auto closing Brackets` settings and I have set it to `languageDefined` but still it is not auto-closing the parenthesis

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLOtJ.png

Please answer how to fix that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is a bug in VSCode 1.57.x: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/127739

For similar issues just search "auto closing" in the issues: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues?q=auto+closing

Answer (score 4):

Actually, this is an issue defined by an extension... are you, by any chance, using [copilot](https://copilot.github.com/)?

Comment: Thank you. Fixed that by removing copilot extension

Answer (score 0):

go to settings and edit settings.json

```
 "editor.autoClosingBrackets": "always",
  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.autoClosingBrackets": "languageDefined"
  },
```

Comment: if you are unable to fix please let me know.